# why is top-margin pushing more than one div down?

Tags: html, css

I want my logo div down further, not exactly center, but about there. When I add a margin to the top it pushed my menu-bar div down too. I tried adding a padding instead by that didn't move the div. I'm guessing because there isn't actually anything in it right? Is there a way to move that div down and over a little without affecting the menu-bar div?

```
<div id="Container">

        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="menu-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a>start</a></li>
                <li><a>end</a></li>
                <li><a>info</a></li>                
                <li><a>score</a></li>                
                <li><a>reload</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

-

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html{
    background:url(../images/water-316625_1280.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;  
}


#menu-bar{
    height:30px;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    background-color:rgba(173,172,172,.9);
    border-radius:10px;
    border:solid rgba(109,186,235,1.00)
    margin-top:0;

}

#menu-bar li{
        float:right;
        padding: 0 10px;
        font-family:Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
        font-size:110%;
        cursor:pointer


}

#logo{

    height:100px;
    background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: Maybe this article could help: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are included the menu items inside the logo container?. It would be a good practice that to allow the `logo` element to independent.  Please see the updated code.

1. Give the float property left for the `#logo` id
2. put `;` after the `border` property for `#menu-bar` id (missing in your code)-  `border:solid rgba(109,186,235,1.00);` and `cursor:pointer` in `#menu-bar li`
3. Please give a `margin-top:0` for the `<ul>` elements as well.

Here are the [JSfilddle](https://jsfiddle.net/091roL6q/)

Answer (score 2):

All CSS properties have a default of "position: static;". This means that all elements are rendered in order that they appear in your html file.

So when you add a "margin-top" to a div (i.e. logo) it will add height to that div while all other divs that follow will have to re-position to accommodate that change.

So margins adds to the height or width of your element. Your logo is "height:100px;" when you add a "margin-top: 15px;" your element has a total height 115px. That is why #menu-bar has moved.

A solution to this would be to set the #logo div to "position: relative;" Then you can use the properties top, left, right, down. To move that element based on it's current position but will not affect other divs in the document. So for example:

```
#logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;}
```

Will move #logo down 20px from its current location.

Hope that helps.

Comment: tried this but didn't work. Tried adding relative to both, or just seperately and it still pushes both down.